# Unable to set selected value for combobox in table row

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a `combobox` in a column of a custom table that is populated dynamically. How can I set the value selected for the row that the `combobox` was changed? Currently, when the `onchange` fires, the selected value is set for every row that is output in the table. I can get the row index of the table and output the key/value and I can get the selected value of the `combobox`, but I can't figure out how I need to set the value for each row individually.

HTML:

```
            <template for:each={products} for:item="product" for:index="indexParent">
                <tr key={product.key}>
                    <td><lightning-input type="checkbox" name="input1"></lightning-input></td>
                    <td>
                        {product.value}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="progress"
                            value={status}
                            placeholder="--Please Select--"
                            options={statuses}
                            onchange={handleStatusChange}                                     
                            data-index={indexParent} >
                        </lightning-combobox> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getProducts from '@salesforce/apex/TestController.getProducts';

export default class TestLWC extends LightningElement {

    status = '';
    @track products = [];
    
    @wire(getProducts)
    wireProductData(result) {
        if(result.data) {
            var conts = result.data;
            for(var key in conts) {
                this.products.push({value:conts[key], key:key })
            }
        }
    }
    
    get statuses() {
        return [
            { label: 'Contracted', value: 'Blue' },
            { label: 'In Progress', value: 'Yellow' },
            { label: 'Live', value: 'Green' },
        ];
    }
    
    handleStatusChange(e) {
        // get the current top level row index of the data table
        const itemIndex = e.currentTarget.dataset.index;
        console.log('************************* itemIndex ' + itemIndex);

        // get row and output the value and key
        const rowData = this.products[itemIndex];
        console.log('************************** rowData value' + rowData.value);
        console.log('************************** rowData key' + rowData.key);

        // get the value selected from the combobox
        console.log('************************* value ' + e.target.value);
        this.status = e.target.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: each row needs its own status value, so you'll need to update your 'products' variable to keep track of the status value for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three changes in your code can fix the problem:-

First, modify the products array to have more attributes in each item. We have added one more attribute i.e. **picklistValue**

```
@wire(getProducts)
wireProductData(result) {
    if(result.data) {
        var conts = result.data;
        for(var key in conts) {
            this.products.push({
                 value:conts[key], 
                 key:key,
                 picklistValue: '' 
            })
        }
    }
}
```

now, In change handler of combobox, you can assign the picklist value to only changed row:-

```
handleStatusChange(e) {
    this.products =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.products));
    // get the current top level row index of the data table
    const itemIndex = e.currentTarget.dataset.index;
    this.products[itemIndex].picklistValue = e.target.value;
}
```

and finally modify your html code by assigning value dynamically from array list to your combobix:-

```
        <template for:each={products} for:item="product" for:index="indexParent">
            <tr key={product.key}>                    
                <td>
                    <lightning-combobox
                        name="progress"
                        value={product.picklistValue}
                        placeholder="--Please Select--"
                        options={statuses}
                        onchange={handleStatusChange}                                     
                        data-index={indexParent} >
                    </lightning-combobox> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
```

Comment: Thank you to you both!